# Firebase custom unique ID

Tags: firebase, emberfire

In my EmberFire app the URL looks like this:

```
http://example.com/friends/-Jaxji0depwt4PE8KnFG
```

Is there a way to customize the unique ID in Firebase to look like this:

```
http://example.com/friends/1
http://example.com/friends/2
http://example.com/friends/3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique id in firebase is generated when we [push](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html) data.

Example:

```
var messageListRef = new Firebase('https://samplechat.firebaseio.com/friends');
var newMessageRef = messageListRef.push();
newMessageRef.set({ 'name': 'fred', 'email': 'fred@yh.com' });
// We've appended a new message to the message_list location.
var path = newMessageRef.toString();
// path will be something like
// 'https://samplechat.firebaseio.com/friends/-IKo28nwJLH0Nc5XeFmj'
```

Instead, we can directly assign value to child

Example:

```
var friendcount = 1;
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://samplechat.firebaseio.com/friends");
myFirebaseRef.child(""+friendcount).set({'name':'f'+friendcount,'email':'e'+friendcount+'@yh.com'});
friendcount = 2;
myFirebaseRef.child(""+friendcount).set({'name':'f'+friendcount,'email':'e'+friendcount+'@yh.com'});
friendcount = 3;
myFirebaseRef.child(""+friendcount).set({'name':'f'+friendcount,'email':'e'+friendcount+'@yh.com'});
```

So, the answer is to use the value directly in child

```
myFirebaseRef.child(1).set({'name':'f1'});
myFirebaseRef.child(2).set({'name':'f2'});
myFirebaseRef.child(3).set({'name':'f3'});
```